# 36V Li-ion Charger - how do we make it actually work?

Tags: lithium-ion, charger

I have a Hitachi Li-ion charger (without the case) that suppose to charge 10 18650 cells in series (hitachi powertool battery made of 10 high drain cells). That's an official 36V rating of the charger that suppose to deliver at least 42V to fully charge a 10-cell li-ion battery.

The charger was used initially exactly for its purpose. Now I wanted to use it to charge various 36V rated batteries but it seems there's a problem: it does not activate (even with almost fully charged battery).

Measuring it not connected does not give a relevant reading.
Connecting a 36V rated battery (+ and -, also made out of 10 cells) to it does not activate the charging process (a LED suppose to go active to signal charging state).

Now, there's a 3rd contact in the charger (that was going to be connected to a 3rd contact of the original battery) but I have no idea what that connector suppose to do. My guess it's a reference or something signaling the charger that a battery is connected so it starts charging.

What else could I try ? Where that 3rd contact suppose to go to activate the charging process ?

I can add a picture of the charger if it helps.

Comment: How about adding a schematic and not a picture?

Comment: If I had the original Hitachi schematic I would not need help with this.

Comment: How do you think an EE would be able to answer this without a schematic?

Comment: Sorry, we forgot our crystal ball...

Answer (score 1):

> how do we make it actually work?

It already works.  It is designed to charge a particular model of battery pack, and it seems it does that correctly.

You apparently want it to do something it is not designed to do.  In this case, the short answer is that you can't, with your apparent knowledge of electronics and the details of this charger and the battery pack it is intended to charge.

The third connection is for communication so something inside the battery pack that you are very unlikely to find specs on.  This probably works with the charger to do cell balancing, and also to make it difficult for third parties to sell replacement battery packs.

These are not the droids you are looking for.  Move along.

Comment: I assumed as much, but the point was to determine how to make it work.

Comment: @Ove: The point is you can't.

Comment: @OlinLathrop is right. Many manufacturers do this to prevent people from using their products in other applications.

Answer (score 1):

The third contact could be a single wire communication port, perhaps using a proprietary protocol, so that the battery charger needs to authenticate (or negotiating with) the battery in order to start charging.

But it could also simply be the internal thermistor contact, used to monitor the internal battery temperature, like in many small batteries. If this is the case, one should see a resistance between this pin and the negative contact. The value is usually a 10kOhm at 25°C, decreasing with increasing temperature (i.e. NTC, negative temperature coefficient), but this isn't a standard.

In the latter case, one can make the charger "see" a 10kOhm resistance in order to start charging.

This is only theory: please be careful.

Comment: I do intent to make some more testing. I notice that other manufacturers use that 3rd wire to have a reference form a single battery cell pair, while others activate the circuit if a proper resistance is detected. I hope it's not a communication port. Anything else and I could make it work.

Comment: I agree. The NTC contact is very common in Li-ion batteries. If this isn't a communication bus in your case, then it's very likely to be a temp. sensing contact, since it would be indeed very dangerous to charge such Li-ion batteries without temperature monitoring.